# iOS : AVFoundation Image Capture Dark

Tags: ios, image, avfoundation, capture

I'm developping an app which captures photos from my iPad front camera.
The photos are coming very **dark**.
Does someone have an idea about how to fix this issue, please ?

Here is my code and some explainations :

1) I initialize my capture session

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    NSArray *devices = [AVCaptureDevice devices];
    AVCaptureDevice *frontCamera;
    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in devices){
        if ([device position] == AVCaptureDevicePositionFront) {
            frontCamera = device;
        }
    }

    if ([frontCamera isExposureModeSupported:AVCaptureExposureModeContinuousAutoExposure]){
        NSError *error=nil;
        if ([frontCamera lockForConfiguration:&error]){
            frontCamera.exposureMode = AVCaptureExposureModeContinuousAutoExposure;
            frontCamera.focusMode=AVCaptureFocusModeAutoFocus;
            [frontCamera unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }

    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *frontFacingCameraDeviceInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:frontCamera error:&error];
    [captureSession addInput:frontFacingCameraDeviceInput];
    [captureSession setSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh];
    captureVideoOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    captureImageOutput =[[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
    [captureSession addOutput:captureVideoOutput];
    [captureSession addOutput:captureImageOutput];

}
```

2) When the user presses the button Record, it starts a timer and preview the content of the camera to a preview layer

```
- (IBAction)but_record:(UIButton *)sender {

    MainInt = 4;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countup) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc]initWithSession:captureSession];
    previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.aView.bounds.size.width, self.aView.bounds.size.height);
    previewLayer.frame = rect;
    [self.aView.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
    [captureSession startRunning];

}
```

3) At the end of the timer, the photo is taken and saved

```
- (void)countup {
    MainInt -=1;
    if (MainInt == 0)  {      
        [timer invalidate];
        timer = nil;

        [captureSession stopRunning];
        AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
        for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in captureImageOutput.connections)
        {
            for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts])
            {
                if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] )
                {
                    videoConnection = connection;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (videoConnection) { break; }
        }

        [captureImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
        {
            CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment( imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
            NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
            stillImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
        }];

        [captureSession startRunning];
        [captureSession stopRunning];
    }  
}
```

4) Finally, when the user press the save button, the image is recorded in a specific album

```
- (IBAction)but_save:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIImage *img = stillImage;
    [self.library saveImage:img toAlbum:@"mySpecificAlbum" withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error)];  
}
```

In fact, all the code works properly but the resulting images are very dark...

Comment: I added the source code

Answer (score 6):

This was happening to me as well and it turned out I was trying to capture too soon and the camera didn't have enough time to stabilize.  I had to add about 0.5 seconds of delay before the pictures would be normal brightness.

HTH

Comment: This helped me a lot! My images were not dark but most were unfocused but this worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on an iOS 7 5th gen ipod touch, but not on a 4th gen ipod touch with iOS 6.1.

I found that the fix is to show a preview of the camera:

```
// Setup camera preview image
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:_captureSession];
[_previewImage.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
```

As instructed at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW22

Note: I did not investigate accomplishing this without a preview